# Tabbed Panel Page:

Tags: html, wicket-6

I am trying to implement an example for tabbed panel page in wicket but it does not work. I have stripped off few methods that i thought were not necessary for my current scenario. I am not sure if i missed something. Please suggest.

TabbedPanelPage Java:

```
 public class TabbedPanelPage extends WebPage {
            Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TabbedPanelPage.class);
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            public TabbedPanelPage() {
                    setDefaultModel(new Model<String>("tabpanel"));
                    log.info("Constructor: ");
                    List<ITab> tabs = new ArrayList<ITab>();
                    log.info("AbstractTab : 1");
                    tabs.add(new AbstractTab(new Model<String>("first tab")) {
                            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                            @Override
                            public Panel getPanel(String panelId) {
                                    log.info("getPanel: 1");
                                    return new TabPanel1(panelId);
                            }

                    });
                    log.info("AbstractTab : 2");
                    tabs.add(new AbstractTab(new Model<String>("second tab")) {
                            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                            @Override
                            public Panel getPanel(String panelId) {
                                    log.info("getPanel: 2");
                                    return new TabPanel2(panelId);
                            }

                    });
                    log.info("AbstractTab : 3");
                    tabs.add(new AbstractTab(new Model<String>("third tab")) {
                            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                            @Override
                            public Panel getPanel(String panelId) {
                                    log.info("getPanel: 3");
                                    return new TabPanel3(panelId);
                            }

                    });

                    add(new TabbedPanel("tabs", tabs));

            }

            private static class TabPanel1 extends Panel {
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TabPanel1.class);

                    public TabPanel1(String id) {
                            super(id);
                            log.info("TabPanel1");
                    }

            }

            private static class TabPanel2 extends Panel {
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TabPanel2.class);

                    public TabPanel2(String id) {
                            super(id);
                            log.info("TabPanel1");
                    }

            }

            private static class TabPanel3 extends Panel {
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TabPanel3.class);

                    public TabPanel3(String id) {
                            super(id);
                            log.info("TabPanel1");
                    }

            }
    }
```

TabbedPanelPage Mark-Up:

```
     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
        <head>
        <title>Wicket Examples - component reference</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div wicket:id="tabs">[tabbed panel will be here]</div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

TabPanel1 Mark-up:

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
        <wicket:panel>
        <br />
        This is tab-panel 1
        </wicket:panel>
        </html>
```

this is the Log:

> Constructor:
>       AbstractTab : 1
>       AbstractTab : 2
>       AbstractTab : 3
>       getPanel: 1
>     TabPanel1.

my application terminates at this point. 
Thanks in advance.

K

Comment: The problem is that the panel does not properly appear on the screen or that you WebApplication terminates after the page is rendered? There is a working example here: http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/ajax/tabbed-panel?0

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. There is nothing wrong with the code, problem was with naming the mark-up for tabpanel. Since the tabpanel is inside the TabbedPanelPage class the mark-up was to be named in accordence.

Eg.

Mark-up page for TabPanel1 has to be TabPanelPage$TabPanel1.html

Cheers